# Alarm Manager and Services Android

Tags: android, service

I am having an issue starting an alarm manager with a service.  The service is initiated from the mainActicity with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

I have defined the service in the manifest using this code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourService"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sjjgames.abortionappnoads.YOURSERVICE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<service android:name=".YourService" />
```

This is what the "YourService" class looks like:

```
package com.sjjgames.abortionappnoads;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    public void onStartCommand(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The service is supposed to call a class called "Alarm" but the service never seems to start.

Comment: It seems that you hava an activity and a service defined with the same name in the Manifest file. What happens (i.e.) if you change your activity name from .YourService to .YourActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OnStartCommand` has the wrong signature, so it is not overriding the base class, it should return an `int`.  Using the `@Override` annotation helps catch these errors.  Be sure to return one of the `START_` codes that correspond to how you want your service run.  See [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) for more details.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
```